# I'm reading some data from Firebase database but it returned object is null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase structure
[Fire Base Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQuq4.jpg)

I am trying to fetch phone value from firebase but it is giving null.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

```
 //getting user id value
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);


    // Reading from SharedPreferences

    String uid = settings.getString("uid", "");
    userId = uid;
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("phone").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            phone = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " +phone);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }

    });

textview.setText(phone);
```

Please give some suggestion i don't know why it is returning null 
Thanks

Comment: Did you check if the userId is the correct Id?

Comment: ya i checked it and  it was correct

Comment: Oh look at your Exception. It says the `mFirebaseDatabase` is null so i guess it is not initialized. Try to use `mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` before calling the `child()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here :

```
string uid = settings.getString("uid","")
```

You're pushing the values using the random key and your code is unable to locate to that key rhat is why its giving `null`

Solution :
In the code where you're pushing the values to the database instead of push just use

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(your value model class variable)
```

Now in your fetching code just replace `uid` with

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
```